# Quick true and false question check

Tags: improper-integrals

[image]

a) False. Counter example $\frac{1}{x}$

b) False. Has to be positive by comparison theorem definition (Cant think of a counter example)

c) True by definite integral properties.

d) True by comparison theorem definition

Comment: I'm sure this is clear in your mind, but if you consider it from the viewpoint of a Reader on Math.SE, it may occur to you that this is not a self-contained presentation of a Question.  Please review [ask].

Comment: b) let $f(x)=-\frac1x$ and $g(x)=\frac1{x^2}$.  This is a counter-example, unless they wanted $0\le f(x)\le g(x)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Does $\int_{x=0}^\infty g(x) \, dx$ really converge, given the lower limit of integration?

Comment: @BrianTung Close enough, you get what I mean.  (for the particular counter-example, just shift it over a bit)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Yes, you're right that I get what you mean.  That comment was for the benefit of the OP, in case they blindly accept the counterexample.

Comment: How is c not true? Isn't it just a constant multiplying into a value. Like for example if it converges to 5 then c is 1. Unless c could be infinity i don't think it would effect it? And for d isnt that just the opposite of the comparison test, I don't really know how to explain it

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The OP and I are questioning your logic on part $c$.  As far as I can see, it is true.

Comment: I put b as false? Is it not false because by comparision theorem they have to be positive?

Comment: @user349557 b is false unless $0\le f(x)$.  Then, it is true.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm extremely sorry about my typing mistake. Yes, your answers for $a,b,c$ are fine, and $d$ is a problem, because taking $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv 1$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Oh so comparison theorem doesnt work opposite ways

Comment: Because $0 \le f \le g$, we have $0 \le \int f \le \int g$ The only way $\int f$ can diverge is if $\int g$ gets out of the way by diverging too. But conversely, if $\int g$ diverges, there is nothing that forces $f$ to go along for the ride. $0 \le e^{-x} \le 1$ for $x \ge 0$, $\int_0^\infty 1dx =\infty$, but $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx =1$.